# Can FreeFileSync back up to directories named for day/week/month?

Tags: windows-backup, freefilesync

Can I configure [FreeFileSYnc](https://freefilesync.org/) to backup to directories named for day/week/month? If so, how?

I prefer full backups, rather than deltas, so would like that feature.

As a bonus, can I run it as a Windows service?

Comment: Have you looked any of this up online? This product has been around a while and there's likely quite a bit of documentation on it, and if it offers these options they'd be documented. So, what research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I looked; no I don't see it; but that does not mean that it is not possible; after all, this is  an outlier case.

Comment: In the event this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), is there a particular reason you need to use FreeFileSync specifically? Your use case sounds like it's antithetical to what the software is intended to do, which is to synchronize two specific directories. That being said, the `.ffs_batch` files created by this software are XML files. You could use a batch script to modify the folders at run-time. If the backup folder is empty, then it should be a full backup by default.